# Modify Default RTF Layout in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to create a new Default layout for "Interactive Reports" so that when user tries to download the data by navigating to "Actions -> Download -> RTF" from the interactive report it should call the new word template that I have created using BI publisher instead of the default layout.

Please advise me on how to implement this. I am using Oracle APEX version 5.1.3.

Thanks,
Ashlesh.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure oracle APEX with BI Publisher check it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1knIDsjn1A

Comment: Hi Azam, Thanks for responding to my query, appreciate your help.

Comment: I understood how we can custom print report content, but how do you print only the filtered rows in the report ?

Example: In your video, you are navigating into the student record and printing out the information for that student only. But my requirement is to provide a button on the "Students" page so that the user can download all the students data into the custom report (I have successfully implemented this as well), the only issue I am facing is with the filtering conditions. 

Suppose, user adds a filtering condition that retrieves only 3 students and then clicks on the download.

Answer (score 0):

I was going though the APEX developers guide and found that "Interactive Reports" do not support custom layouts.

"Note: 
Interactive reports do not support a custom report layout." (section Developing Reports 10-83 in APEX developer guide) this was in APEX 5.0, can some one confirm if this is the case in 5.1.3 as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to resolve this issue by following the approach stated below.

1) "Note: Interactive reports do not support a custom report layout." (section Developing Reports 10-83 in APEX developer guide) this was in APEX 5.0, can some one confirm if this is the case in 5.1.3 as well ?

2) By making use of the routine "DOWNLOAD_PRINT_DOCUMENT" (please refer "APEX API guide" for a detailed explanation), we can download the printed document.

3) The data to the printed doc can be provided via XML as BLOB or XML (in UTF-8 format) as CLOB to the routine "DOWNLOAD_PRINT_DOCUMENT".

4) Lastly, this call out to the "DOWNLOAD_PRINT_DOCUMENT" should be within a process to work